# Regex in R to reverse string split

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to split a variable string into it's components for use in a dataframe later, but I struggling to find a way to do a reverse regex to find a string between two characters.

My string is as follows:

```
20581 Buzz Testing Nathan 3 BUZZRETJOUCHUALLA_D1C - Churned - Stage 1 Other 28-February-2019.csv
```

I am trying to extract the date from the left of the "." up to the first space it encounters, which should give me the date.

I have tried a few different Regex checkers online, but none seem to translate very well to R.

I have also provided some example code I have used for successfully splitting other elements of the text string:

```
regmatches(file_list, regexpr("(?<=\\- )[^ -]+", file_list, perl=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will get you the non-space string (which is the date `28-February-2019` you require) after the last literal `.` in your string,

```
\S+(?=\.[^.]*$)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K891Wz/1)**

Check out this R code,

```
file_list <- "20581 Buzz Testing Nathan 3 BUZZRETJOUCHUALLA_D1C - Churned - Stage 1 Other 28-February-2019.csv"
regmatches(file_list, regexpr("\\S+(?=\\.[^.]*$)", file_list, perl=TRUE));
```

Prints,

```
[1] "28-February-2019"
```

**[Online R Demo](https://rextester.com/LTGJC95101)**